# 'Can not determine workspaces' error -> Azure DevOps Services and Build Agent on VM

Tags: azure-devops, build-agent

I'm trying to set Build Server machine in way that Build Agent is configured on it, and is targeting Azure DevOps Service (Cloud) collection, or organization as it is named like that for now. There is established connection but problem that I'm faced with is regarding workspaces.

When I try to run build definition, checkout step fails due to "Can not determine workspace..." error. As I run the advised command

```
 tf workspaces /collection:<collection_url>
```

on Build Server, I can build given project, but, when try another project, the same story. I have to run the mentioned command again (new workspace is appeared in the list) and then I'm able to build that project.

Can someone point me on right way in diagnostic or tell the cause/solution if faced with this already?

Comment: Was the agent on the build server previously connected to a different TF server or Azure DevOps installation? I would try completely removing the agent and [re-adding it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent).  If it was a migration you might want to audit what workspaces you have on that server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758543/azure-devops-deleting-workspace

Comment: Eric, thank you for advice. It is about new BA from the scratch which is set on new VM up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/902570/can-not-determine-workspaces-error-azure-devops-se.html) which i assume is also posted by you,seems the agent in Azure DevOps is the one you used in TFS which is called as migration.

> As I run the advised command
>
> `tf workspaces /collection:<collection_url>`
>
> on Build Server, I can build given project, but, when try another project, the same story.

It looks like the build definition requires a specific workspace which you managed by manual command.

What about create a new agent in Azure DevOps which is quite simple see if the problem can be resolved.

Comment: Yang, thank you for the response.Yes, I that is posted by me, also. I created a new VM after the migration which serves as Build server and so set a new BA up on it.

Comment: Seems it's the migration that causes the problem since the VM and BA are new as you said. What about create a brand new Orgnization and do the same operations with a new VM and BA see if the problem can be reproduced?