# Cant get rid of a workspace problem in TFS2018 after migration

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-2018

I have a problem after migrating from TFS2013 to TFS2018.
This happened after a major rebuild of our system.
I migrated the TFS DB and software and can check all things in the web browser where it looks ok.
I deleted all workspaces on the Server.

Example of my problem:
I opened with VS2019 a project (WOL) and tried to connect to the TFS server.
I got a suggested workspace directory:

```
C:\Users\Juergen.JLOEWNEREDV\Source\Workspaces\WOL
```

I tried to change this to another local directory where the project already exists for its lifetime:

```
D:\Visual Studio Projekte\WOL
```

(As the TFS server was longer time offline, there were many changes to the project which I want to check in now)
On this try I get the following message:

```
The working folder
*D:\Visual Studio Projekte\WOL*
is already in use by the workspace JLOEWNER;Juergen Loewner on computer JLOEWNER.
```

I found no way how to get rid of this.

Can anybody help me?

There are many more projects pending for check in. So I need a general procedure which solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is `The working folder D:\Visual Studio Projekte\WOL is already in use by the workspace JLOEWNER;Juergen Loewner on computer JLOEWNER.`

The variable `D:\Visual Studio Projekte\WOL` stands for the blocked folder, `JLOEWNER` for the workspace/machine name and `Juergen` for the users id on Azure DevOps Server(TFS2018).

We could run the [tf.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) cmd to delete Remote Workspace.

Steps:

Run `Developer Command Prompt` with **Administrator** privileges from Visual Studio 2019 and login with your Azure DevOps credentials. If the Login dialog doesn’t show up, force it by executing:

```
tf.exe workspace
```

Get a list of all remote workspaces available in your DevOps Collection by running the command:

```
tf.exe workspaces /computer:* /owner:* /format:xml > c:\temp\workspaces.xml
```

Find the abandoned workspace in the list and note its name and ownerid for running the command:

```
tf workspace /delete {WORKSPACE.name};{WORKSPACE.ownerid}
```

We could check this [blog](https://kiko.io/categories/Tools/TFS-DevOps-Delete-Remote-Workspace/) for more details.

Or refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765973/13903626) to remove the workspace, then it should be work.

Comment: Got it!It solved my workspace assignment problem.

Comment: How do I make my local changes now checked in into the existing(!) project?
Can you help me here too?
Thanks in advance.
Juergen